# How to add item into jcombobox

Tags: java, netbeans, jcombobox

I have to add item to jComboBox from Database.
I am using Netbeans and do not know in which event of jComboBox this adding item method should
be placed .

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question fully but I think you want something like this:

```
String[] petStrings = { "Bird", "Cat", "Dog", "Rabbit", "Pig" };
JComboBox box = new JComboBox(petStrings);
....
box.addItem("Mouse");
```

This would give you a general idea...

Here is a sample function that I used for a SELECT statement to query and get a result set and return a Vector of Strings:

```
// Function to search the DB and return a vector containing the search
// results. The passed in value is a String used in a LIKE SQL search.
public Vector<String> Search(String query, int cid){
    Vector<String> retVal = new Vector<String>();

    try {
        // A SQL statement
        Statement st = DBObject.conn.createStatement();

        // Get result set.
        ResultSet r = st.executeQuery("SELECT filename FROM " +
                "[P2P].[dbo].[FILE] WHERE filename LIKE '" + query + "' " +
                "AND shared=1 AND client_ID!=" + cid + ";");

        // Iterate through the results.
        while(r.next()){
            retVal.add(r.getString("filename"));
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return retVal;
}
```

The DBObject class:

```
abstract public class DBObject {
static Connection conn;
boolean valid;

// This tells us if we can use the object.
public boolean isValid() { return valid; }
}
```

How to connect to the DB:

```
// Set the connection string.
connectString = "jdbc:sqlserver://" + args[0] + ";user=P2P;password=1234;";
```

Comment: Mr.Bunk ..., i want to know where try and catch method for connecting database for adding item to combobox is placed. Is try and catch method placed in jcomboboxactionactionperformed(...) or somewhere else ?

Comment: Hi @amish3110. The JComboBox.actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) method doesn't indicate it throws an exception. Can you post a little bit more of you code in your original question (edit it), then I can help you out. I'm guessing this should be an easy one to answer... I need to see a bit more of how you connect to the Database.

Comment: Mr.Bunk... I have sql server 2005 .there i have one table name data which has slno,name,type,shape as column fields
i want to display the records of name,type,shape in textbox on combobox selection of slno...i have got the slno from database..but coding to display remaining details from databse i dont know sir..

Comment: @amish3110, I updated my post to include some sample code. Can you edit your original post to show what `you` have tried please?